# How to block local merges on a specific branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have the "production" branch and I need to block merges to this branch, which can only be done by merge request.

The repository is in bitbucket, I already configured the branch restriction, leaving only the admin user as the only user to approve and merge branches. Operating from the bitbucket everything works fine. And there are the other users with read or write privileges.

The problem is that if from my local configured as a low-privileged user, I commit to a new branch and merge that same one to the "production" branch, it does so without problems and all the bitbucket configuration is skipped.

In short, I need the production branch to be locked to merges and commits.
That can only be done through pull requests.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can only set up branch protection in GitHub, GItLab, BitBucket, etc. That means that, although you can commit locally, the user won't be able to actually push the changes to the remote repository. If this is the behavior you want, all you have to do is setup branch protection: https://spectralops.io/blog/how-to-set-up-git-branch-protection-rules/

Comment: But you mean.... you are merging _locally_?

Comment: I mean, nothing against merging locally, all the opposite... it's just that I would assume that it would be clear that the restriction applies to branches on the provider's repo.... in your local you can go nuts as you **own** your local repo, it's one of the tenets of distributed VCSs. The trick here is that even if I merge into my **local** `production` branch, I **won´t** be able to push into the **remote** `production` branch that I protected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Branch protection features in git hosting services (BitBucket, GitHub, GitLab, etc) protect against **pushes** to protected branches that would impact the repository shared with other users. There is no way to enforce branch protection on a user's local clone of a repository, due to the way `git` works. However as soon as they attempt to push a commit forbidden by the branch protection rules on your hosting service, they will get an error.

Comment: It was happening to me that the branch rule was configured wrong in bitbucket, when I managed to configure it correctly, I got the error. Thanks!
Issue close!